# Как Google реагирует на спрятанный контент?

Tags: css, seo, css-filters

В процессе создания платной подписки на музыкальном сайте наткнулись на вопрос:
**Как будет реагировать Google бот (при обходе страницы) на спрятанный контент посредствами css?**

Скриншот [страницы](https://eproves.com/ru/background-no-copyright-music/gaming/):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Контент прячем только с помощью CSS

```
filter: blur();
user-select: none;
```

**Логический вывод:**
Бот пробегает по HTML коду страницы.
И раз сам контент там присутствует, то проблем возникнуть не должно.
Но так ли оно в действительности?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На бота фильтр блюр никак не влияет, так как он видит исходный код в чистом виде и работает с ним, соответственно, что вы скрываете посредством css обычному пользователю не видно, но видно боту ПС.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Придерживаемся такого же мышления.
Однако от Google можно ожидать многое, поэтому важно знать есть ли у него факторы, которые мониторят действия CSS / JS. Помимо поведенческих самих пользователей на странице, которые конечно же упадут.

Comment: @KobetsMatviy проблема с css может у сайта возникнуть только в том случае, если сайт не адаптирован под мобильные устройства, работа алгоритма это определяет. А вот у Яндекса есть фильтр, который можно получить за скрытие текста стилями display:none  с целью манипулирования выдачей, переспам и так далее, в вашем  случае для 2-х ПС нет волнения.

Comment: Ничто ему (боту) не мешает скачать CSS файл и определить, виден ли текст юзеру или нет ...

Comment: @Roman Grinov Судя скрины ТС в нее скрыт не текст, а фото, поэтому не вижу проблемы

Answer (score 1):

Возможные варианты:

**Худший**. Скрытый текст воспринимается как **[сигнал спама](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/hidden-text-links)**.

**Лучший**. Скрытый текст воспринимается как неважное или неинтересное или нерелевантное содержание и как результат - понижение поискового ранга для скрытого текста, но не для всего содержания.

Как часто бывает многое зависит от деталей, например цель скрытия текста, связь скрытого текста с главным содержанием и так далее.

Comment: Оно то так. Но здесь же стоит и вопрос: воспринимается ли filter(blur) как скрытие?
К примеру на Forbes прячут контент с помощью display: none - это уже явный признак скрытия.

Comment: Нет явного указания об этом элементе как о спаме. Однако размытие можно воспринимать как скрытие. Лучше избегать это.